# How to encode URL in react and react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm developing a react application where the progress of actions done in sequence way like stepper kind of the thing, But i need to go with routing for this process.

For example say, [image]
     User is need to upload some data in first step based on the data, The seconds step (in our case, another Route will be render). Like so on. Totally there are 7 steps.

What is want is, User need not to enter the url path manually in URL bar without following the each step.

Checking the props in each route is not a good i think , Is there any way of doing this like URL encoding with long URL that are not understandable by the client.

Comment: post some code that you have tried

Comment: To be frank, I don't know how url encoding works.

Comment: I don't think "url encoding" is what you think it is. You could use a super long, convoluted path element and/or query parameter in the URL, but you'll still be checking them via props in react(react-router-dom). React router allows passing state to the next pushed route so you can use that instead of the URL to see if a user has validly entered your flow and not leak info out to the browser window (as easily).